# Select rows from DataFrame based on value from one of the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, where-clause, keyerror

[DataFrame named "result"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATEvR.png)

**I am trying to get rows with the `values == 0` from a DataFrame (named "`result`" that you see in the image attached).
The SQL Query for something like this will be like:
`SELECT * FROM RESULT WHERE` column_name equal to some_value
My DataFrame has 2 columns. the 1st one is i think named '`Index`' and the 2nd one is named '`0`' (the names are by default -- didn't bother to change)

Because the 2nd column is a binary: based on whether the restaurant review (1st column) was positive or negative (1 or 0). I want to get only the rows (of the two columns based on the negative reviews).
when I try the code: 
`df.loc[df['column_name'].isin(some_values)]`     or in my case
`result.loc[result['0'].isin(0)]`

I get the error: `KeyError: '0'`

Can anybody please help? **

Comment: check the output of `result.columns`: you should be able to see if the column `0` has an `int` for a column name, or a `str`. then, you can use `result.loc[result['0'] == 0 ]` if it is a `str` or `result.loc[result[0] == 0 ]` if it is an `int`. if you want to use `.isin`, you need to pass a list (`.isin([0])`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select rows, whose value of column '0' is 0, it should be as simple as :

```
result[result[0] == 0]
```

However, as [sacul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6671176/sacul) has pointed out, you should check whether the name of your column is of type 'str' or 'int'.

Comment: The code snippet : result.loc[result[0] == 0 ]  worked well. So the name had a str after all. Great work! I appreciate everything!